# Elements are not displayed when resizing the form via double click on notifyIcon

Tags: c#, winforms

My Winforms program has a color gradient which paints the background with a gradient reaching from one color to another via `Linear Gradient Brush`. It also has a `notifyIcon` to minimize the tool to the system tray and showing it full again when double clicking on the icon. The showing-part works well but all the elements on the form like labels, buttons and so on are crossed in red.

Error message: `Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height equal to 0.`

Code for LinearGradientBrush:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
       using (LinearGradientBrush LiGraBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.LightBlue, Color.MediumBlue, 90F))
       {
               e.Graphics.FillRectangle(LiGraBrush, this.ClientRectangle);
       }
}
```

Code for the resize-event:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            }
  this.Invalidate();
}
```

The gradient code is from [this tutorial](https://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/how-to-paint-a-gradient-background-for-your-forms/) where I also got the `this.Invalidate` from:

I also used the `this.Invalidate` in the double click event of the `notifyIcon`.

(Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, .NET 5.0 and C#)

Comment: Don't call Invalidate() when you've just hidden the form, nothing needs painting.  And add the check that the ClientSize is large enough to produce a meaningful gradient: if (ClientSize.Width == 0 || ClientSize.Height == 0) return;

Comment: Add `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` in the Form Constructor. Remove `Invalidate();` -- Don't subscribe to the Paint event in your Form, override `OnPaint` instead.

Comment: ...but it's probably better if you override `OnPaintBackground` here: it looks like you want to paint the entire background of a Form.

Comment: @HansPassant almost. I used 
`this.ClientRectangle.Width > 0 && this.ClientRectangle.Height > 0)
{
    //painting
}`
and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Check if the Width and Height of `ClientRectangle` are bigger than 0, like so:

```
if (this.ClientRectangle.Width > 0 && this.ClientRectangle.Height > 0)
{
    //paint
}
```